# How to attach properly spaced subscripts to a rotated symbol?

Tags: graphics, formatting, symbols, rotating, scaling

I'd like to attach letters to my rotated symbol and then shrink it down. However, when I do this, the spacing is very much different than when I do the same exact thing to the original symbol. Is there some way to correct and have the rotated symbol look like the original symbol?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows3}       {LS2}{stixtt}   {m} {n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Otimes}{\mathbin}{arrows3}{"A8}

\newcommand{\Oplus}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\Otimes$}}

\newcommand{\Stimes}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\Otimes_R}{\otimes}}}
\newcommand{\Splus}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\Oplus_R}{\oplus}}}


\begin{document}

$M_i \Stimes M_j$ vs $M_i \Splus M_j$.

\end{document}
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Thanks for using my `scalerel` package, but I think that egreg's solution is much nicer in this case.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I love his solution! And aside from the problem I presented above, your `scalerel` package has served me wonderfully in accomplishing what I've needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about `scalerel`, but with a different implementation, the size seems good.

First of all, I load the font at a different scale, instead of scaling down the symbol. Then some `\mathpalette` and box trickery allows to make `\Oplus` into having the same dimensions as `\Otimes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LS2}{stixtt}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{LS2}{stixtt}{m}{n} {<-> s*[.7] stix-mathtt}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows3}{LS2}{stixtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Otimesop}{\mathbin}{arrows3}{"A8}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Otimes}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\O@times\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\O@times}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th#1\Otimesop$}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Oplus}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\O@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\O@plus}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\Otimes$}%
  \sbox\tw@{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\m@th#1\Otimes$}}%
  \dp\tw@=\dp\z@ \ht\tw@=\ht\z@
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \makebox[\wd\z@]{\box\tw@}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Stimes}{\Otimes_R}
\newcommand{\Splus}{\Oplus_R}


\begin{document}

$\Otimes\Oplus$ {\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{$\Otimes$}\fbox{$\Oplus$}}

$M_i \Stimes M_j$ vs $M_i \Splus M_j$.

$M_i \Splus M_j$

\end{document}
```

[image]